# Finding a prime number in Scheme using natural recursion

Tags: recursion, racket

I'm still plugging away at the exercises in How to Design Programs on my own, but have managed to get stuck again. This time it's question 11.4.7:

> Develop the function
>   is-not-divisible-by<=i. It consumes a
>   natural number [>=1], i, and a natural
>   number m, with i < m. If m is not
>   divisible by any number between 1
>   (exclusive) and i (inclusive), the
>   function produces true; otherwise, its
>   output is false.
>
> Use is-not-divisible-by<=i to define
>   prime?, which consumes a natural
>   number and determines whether or not
>   it is prime.

The first part I didn't have too hard a time with:

```
;; A natural number [>=1] is either 1. 1 or 
;; 2. (add1 n) where n is a natural number [>=1].

;; is-not-divisible-by<=i : N[>=1] N -> boolean
(define (is-not-divisible-by<=i i m)
  (cond
    [(= i 1) true]
    [else (cond
            [(= (remainder m i) 0) false]
            [else (is-not-divisible-by<=i (sub1 i) m)])]))
(is-not-divisible-by<=i 3 6) ; expected: false.
(is-not-divisible-by<=i 6 7) ; expected: true.
```

But I just can't see how I can use one variable to do this while using natural recursion. I thought about using a list, but that presents the same problems.

The only solution I can see is giving another variable--let's say x-- the same value as n, and then just doing it the way is-not-divisible-by<=i does it. But I think the authors intend for me to do it some other, simpler way. (And I don't even know how to do what I described anyway, haha.)

This problem has really been busting my butt, so any help or hints, if you could, would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prime number is a number that cannot be divided by any number smaller than itself. You have already implemented the "cannot be divided by any number smaller than" part:

```
(define (prime? n)
  (is-not-divisible-by<=i (sub1 n) n))
```

Comment: Oh, jeeze, that's embarrassing. I thought the entire time that if I did that, the value of both n's would continue to fall by one, every time the function was called recursively. I didn't think (sub1 n) would be treated like an x, but as an n, which doesn't make much sense at all.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's all a matter of whether you think in terms of values (can't be changed) or variables (can be changed)... http://www.nicollet.net/2010/01/quick-test/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

(prime? 1) gets a "division by zero" error.

here is a modified version of the original code. It takes care of (prime? 1) problem for now.

```
(define (prime? p)
  (define (non-divisible-by n d)
    (cond
     ((= d 1) #t)
     (else (if(= (remainder n d) 0)
          #f
          (non-divisible-by n (- d 1))))))
  (if (= p 1)
      #t
      (non-divisible-by p (- p 1))))
```

Now (prime? 1) returns #t

Comment: Note that you should return `#f` in case of 1, as 1 is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you divide all of the numbers from n-1 to 2 to check primality. You only need to check from (floor (sqrt n)). So a faster aproach (specially for large numbers), that also takes care about the undefined (prime? 1) problem, is:

```
(define (prime? n)
  (is-not-divisible-by<=i (floor (sqrt n)) n))
```